# how django will behave if i call object save method in pre_save method of this object?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, relationship

I've two models A and B.

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    relate_to_b = models.Charfield(max_length=100) 

class B(models.Model):
    b_name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    a = OneToOne('A', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                        null=True, default=None, related_name='b_a'
```

when i save object A in pre_save_a method i change something in object B and in pre_save_b change A object and save it.

question: is django call save method object A twice or doing all in first method?

Comment: i recommend you this good tuto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239768/how-django-will-behave-if-i-call-object-save-method-in-pre-save-method-of-this-o

Comment: @cizario good answer, man. i'm understand, thank you